# How to use and configure logback in Adobe CQ5 projects?

Tags: java, aem, logback

I newbie in CQ5. I started my first project in CQ and **I want to write any exceptions and debug info of project's components, services and servlets (in bundles) to log files in crx-repo (...\crx-quickstart\logs)**.

I want to use slf4j with logback implementation in my project.

I tried below steps:

1. Add dependencies in project's pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.7</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
       <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
       <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add logback.xml with configuration (loggers and appenders) to
   project's bundle resource package.
3. Try to instantiate new logger in service (for example):

   ```
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    .....

    @Component(metatype = true, label = "Some", description = "Sone service" , 
    immediate = true)
    @Service(SomeService.class)

    public class SomeService {        

        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDao.class);
        .....
        logger.debug("debug");
        logger.info("info");
        logger.error("error");
        ......
     }
   ```

These steps (It isn't work, of course) I gave an example because i don't know how really work with logback in Adobe CQ5. **Any suggestions?** I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CQ does log to `crx-quickstart/logs/error.log` with its default configuration, and the underlying Apache Sling framework provides the necessary bridge so you just need to acquire an slf4j `Logger` and write to that.

The Java code of your `SomeService` example looks correct to me but in the pom you only need the `slf4j-api` dependency, with scope `provided`, as API and implementation packages are provided by the CQ runtime.

You can also have a look at a Sling sample like [Slingbucks](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingbucks) which will log to that `error.log` if installed on a default CQ instance.